# jQuery does not change height property on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make some boxes the same size, and everything seems to work except the height property - when I try to change it dynamically through the jQuery.

Value seems to be ok, it prints correctly to the console when I'm resizing the window, and the background-color prop also works as expected. Could someone please point what am I missing something here..?

EDIT: if I put some value manually like 300, it works as expected as well...so I guess it has something to do with the variable imageHeight..

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Images {
    constructor() {
        this.images = $('.box-image');
        this.imageHeight = this.images[0].height;
        this.boxes = $('.content-box');
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        $(window).resize(this.boxAdjustment.bind(this));
    }

    boxAdjustment () {
        if(this.images.length > 0) {
            this.adjustHeight();
        }
    }

    adjustHeight() {
        console.log(this.imageHeight);

        $(this.boxes).each(function (i, element) {
            $(element).css({'height': this.imageHeight + 'px'});
            $(element).css({'background-color': '#f1f1f1'});
        });
    }
}

export default Images;
```

Comment: What do you get when you console.log `this.boxes` after the line `this.images = $('.box-image')` ?

Comment: this comes out: (3) [div.content-box, div.content-box, div.content-box, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
0
:
div.content-box
1
:
div.content-box
2
:
div.content-box
length
:
3
prevObject
:
jQuery.fn.init(1)
__proto__
:
Object(0)

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're trying to access a specific image as though it were in an array, but jQuery returns the HTML element, so `this.images[0]` is undefined.  Try [.first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) instead.

Comment: Actually, console.log(this.images[0]); prints the image as supposed..I have three images all the same height, so I just want to use that value to set the values of div's next to them. Now when I pay more attention, it seems that the resize() prints the only one value, so only one image height(depending on the window size). Maybe this isn't a proper way to call the window.resize..?

Answer (score 0):

I overcomplicated and did not call resize properly, did it this way instead:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Images {
    constructor() {
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var images = $('.box-image');
            var imageHeight = images[0].height;
            var boxes = $('.content-box');

            console.log(imageHeight);

                if(images.length > 0) {
                    $(boxes).each(function (i, element) {
                        $(element).css({'height': imageHeight + 'px'});
                        $(element).css({'background-color': '#f1f1f1'});
                    });
                }

        });
    }
}

export default Images;
```